# Powershell jq command emits no result

Tags: powershell, jq

Bash works as expected

```
$ echo '{"foo": "0"}' | jq 'select(.foo == "0")'
{
  "foo": "0"
}
```

But in Powershell,

```
PS> echo '{"foo": "0"}' | jq 'select(.foo == "0")'
PS>
```

Why powershell results this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to backslash the doublequotes unfortunately.

```
'{"foo": "0"}
{"foo": "1"}' | jq -c 'select(.foo == \"0\")'

{"foo":"0"}
```